# Is it possible to take picture using voice command in iOS app?

Tags: ios, ios8, uiimagepickercontroller, voice-control

I created a sample application that uses custom controls to take a picture. Now I want to take a picture using a voice command (like if the user says "capture photo"). Are there any default controls or options in iOS or do we need to implement our own? Any references?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Are there any default controls or options in iOS or do we need to implement our own?

As of iOS 8, there is no Apple-provided speech-to-text API. You can use [SpeechKit](http://nuancemobiledeveloper.com/public/index.php), or implement one of the hacks that uses the Google Voice API.

Answer (score 2):

> Now I want to take a picture using a voice command (like if the user says "capture photo"). Are there any default controls or options in iOS...

There's an **iOS 13** new feature called **Voice Control** that will allow you to reach your goal.

Activate this feature as follows:
[image]

You can find useful information in the `Customize Commands` section like taking a screenshot for instance *(taking a photo with the camera works as well)*:
[image]

If you need dedicated names to be read out in your app, use the **`accessibilityUserInputLabels`** property to define them.

It's now **possible to take picture using the Voice Control feature in iOS app** but **only since iOS 13**.